# Android List view activity

Tags: android

Hi  I am getting values from URL and displayed in the List view .I want the delete values in list view one bye one using button

Comment: I am not getting your problem. When you click button from first file, another button displayed means? Can you give details? what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi I am getting values from URL and displayed in the List view .I want the delete values in list view one bye one using button

Comment: One by one means from which position? i mean from last, from first or from any other position?

Answer (score 0):

The below code is going to remove last item from the ListView:

```
dataAdapter.remove(dataAdapter.getItem(dataAdapter.getCount() - 1));
```